# EntityManager refresh still returns stale data

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a code which calls another api to update data in the same table that i also use. My problem is I don't see the data being refreshed on my side even after calling refresh on entity manager. I enabled hibernate trace logging and I can clearly see the query there and also the response values in the binding trace. The problem is all that is stale data. I am 100% sure that the update was committed to db (We put a sleep in other api before returning and I can manually query the db to see it was updated before I get the response back)

```
public void func(SomeEntity someEntity){ // this entity was found by entity manager previously
        LOGGER.info("SomeEntity before call to API {{}}",someEntity.toString());
        String url = "....some get http url which modifed the table "
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        //..check response etc...
        entityManager.refresh(someEntity);
        LOGGER.info("Reloaded SomeEntity after call to return creation API {{}}",someEntity.toString()); // same old data here
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not using 2nd lvl cache ?

Comment: While the other one may have been committed, that doesn't mean that this current transaction can read it. Try `entityManager.getTransaction().commit();` (or rollback) then `entityManager.getTransaction().begin();` before the `refresh` if you're not using JTA.

Comment: @sajith, it is disabled by default and i dont remeber enabling it. How can i be sure?

Comment: @coladict, that might work but the entity manager refresh is designed to avoid exactly that, i.e reload data during a transaction without having to start a new one. So would that not work?

Comment: if it is hibernate it you should see hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache enabled. It either has to be 2nd level cache or, DB  isolation level that causes you to see the stale data.

Comment: @smi the database's own transaction likely does not allow you to read new data from after it started. I think that's the default behavior in PostgreSQL.

Comment: @SajithSilva, Wow, DB isolation level is something new to me and now I think this may be the cause as my server is set to REPETEABLE_READ globally. I am trying to find a way to use READ_COMMITED for a single hibernate transaction. Do you know off the top of your head?

Comment: @SajithSilva, You were right. It had to do with isolation level. I had to query with a new session to get the fresh data. If you post you comment as answer. I would love to mark it as accepted answer. Thanks